# How do I set the parent of a widget after the widget has already been initlized (ex. if the widget is a parameter to a function call)?

Tags: c++, qt

I know that usually parents are set by being given in the constructor argument, for example if you wanted to have a push button within a frame you could do:

```cpp
QFrame frame = new QFrame();
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(frame);
```

But I already have the push button that I want to add as a child to a frame (it was received as an argument in the call to the function I'm working on).

Is there any way to add an already existing widget as a child to another widget? Or add a new child to an existing or nonexistent parent?

Comment: [`QWidget::setParent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent)?

Comment: @G.M. What in the world. How did I not find that. Thank you very much, that was what I was looking for...how did you find that? I Googled a bunch and looked through a bunch of different doc pages including that of QWidget

Comment: @G.M. I had the audacity to post your comment in the form of an answer. Drop me a note if you want to post it yourself, I'll just delete mine.

Comment: @CharonX Nope, that's fine.  Not a problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: Answer blatantly stolen from G.M.'s comment (with permission - see above ;))

Simply use [`QWidget's`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) [`setParent(QWidget *parent)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) method.

Note: The new parent takes ownership of the `QWidget` (i.e. deallocating it when the parent is destroyed etc.) and you will need to call `show()` on the widget again to make it visible, as changing parents turns `QWidget`s invisible.